# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

Tags: json, jq

i am trying to read for a big json data structure and I get the message:

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

The command that I'm using is the next one:

```
n_rules=$(echo rulebase_list | jq '.total')
```

and the file has in the first hierarchy level a variable which is

```
"total" : 126
```

Do you know why im experiencing problems with that?
I suppose that the problem is that 126 is a numeric value but what can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Carefully check your script against the one you posted in the question. If they match then the answer is very easy.

There is no `"total" : 126` in the string you pass to `jq` because you pass it the output of `echo rulebase_list` that is `rulebase_list`.

What you probably wanted is to send to `jq` the content of the `rulebase_list` file and the tool for this is `cat`:

```
n_rules=$(cat rulebase_list | jq '.total')
```

Alternatively (and faster) is to redirect the input of `jq` from the file:

```
n_rules=$(jq '.total' < rulebase_list)
```

Or to specify the input file name as the last argument in the command line of `jq`:

```
n_rules=$(jq '.total' rulebase_list)
```

Read more about `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `$` in your script. Add it and it'll be fixed.

```
n_rules=$(echo $rulebase_list | jq '.total')
```