# how to trigger and monitor Jenkins job from CI and getting results after is finished

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to implement a script in gitlab CI to trigger a smoke test via Jenkins and then get the results.

So far I am able to trigger the job successfully and I am trying to follow [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/trigger-jenkins-job-from-gitlab-ci-with-parameters/5313#5313) to implement a monitoring stage and then get the result once the job finishes.

my issue is that I implemented a while loop to monitor if the Jenkins job has finished so far the script is giving either syntax errors (when copied in gitlab) or if run in the terminal I get:

```
job is building? true
waiting...
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
job is still building?
job is building?
```

This is what I am using so far:

```
#!/bin/bash


running="true"
while [ "$running" != "false" ]
do 
 echo "job is building? ${running}"
 
 echo "waiting...";
 
 sleep 2;
 running=$(curl -s --user ${EMAIL}:${TOKEN} ${URL}/${var}/lastBuild/api/json  | jq .'building')

 echo "job is still building? ${running}"
  
done


echo "Done!"

buildNumber=$(curl -s --user $EMAIL:$TOKEN ${URL}/$ENV-${var}/lastBuild/api/json  | jq ".url" | awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1)}')

echo "getting results for build ${buildNumber}"

curl -s --user ${EMAIL}:${TOKEN} ${URL}/${ENV}-${var}/lastBuild/api/json  | jq ".url" | awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1)}'

curl -v --silent  --user ${EMAIL}:${TOKEN} ${URL}/${ENV}-${var}/lastBuild/consoleText  2>&1 | grep -i "finished:"
```

---

**UPDATE**

the script is running now ok in my local terminal

the change was

```
running="true"
while [ "$running" != "false" ]
do 
 echo "job is building? ${running}"
 
 echo "waiting..."
 
 sleep 2
     curl -s --user $EMAIL:$TOKEN $URL/$ENV-${var}/lastBuild/api/json  --output now.txt
    
     running=$(jq .'building' now.txt)
 echo "job is still building? ${running}"
  
done
```

The problem is still on Gitlab CI as after copy pasting this script I get in the pipeline

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 149: syntax error: unexpected "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

comes from the line that does the curl

```
running=$(curl -s --user ${EMAIL}:${TOKEN} ${URL}/${var}/lastBuild/api/json  | jq .'building')`
```

I'm assuming that the error is thrown by `jq` when it tries to parse the json and fails. Since this line has an error, the variable `running` never gets properly updated, meaning that the rest of the script doesn't work as intended.

If you fix this line, the rest of your pipeline should work. Consider looking into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280090/parse-error-invalid-numeric-literal-at-line-2-column-0) which has a similar problem  and some solutions.